# Python xarray load specific points and variables of a nc file

Tags: python, performance, python-xarray, netcat

I have 3 `.nc` files, 6 Gb each. They all hold multiple variables, but I am interested in only 2 in particular: `v` and `mid_dates` (13000 x 330 x 300 arrays, where 13000 is the time axis).

I have an a dataframe of size 200x2, the columns represent the coordinates `xpoint` and `ypoint` of 200 points. The `.nc` each have 2 arrays `x` and `y` which are the coordinates representing the arrays cited above (`len(x) = 300`, `len(y) = 330` ).  I use `nc_file.v.sel(x=xpoint,y=ypoint,method='nearest')` in a loop over the my dataframe to extract the v values of my 200 points.

However I can not load all the `.nc` files (datacubes) because my computer's RAM is not big enough.
Is there a way to load only the cells of my `v` and `mid_dates` arrays corresponding to my 200 point, for each of my `.nc` files ?

The only way I found to make it work was: at each iteration in the loop, open each file individually, extract the corresponding `v` and `mid_date` values, close the file, load the other etc.... but it's really slow.

Comment: Have you looked at [`xr.open_dataset`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html#xarray.open_mfdataset), especially with the `parallel=True` flag? The xarray docs on [reading multi-file datasets](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#reading-multi-file-datasets) provide a good overview. Note that additional keyword arguments are passed to open_dataset for each file so you can pass `drop_variables=list_of_vars_to_drop` to exclude variables you don't need

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I tried several options but because my date dimension is not monotonically increasing I get a ValueError keeeping me from opening the datasets. I tried to use the open function with the parallel flag, but it crashed my kernel everytime.

Comment: Do you have to use those .nc files? Maybe some other format will be more convenient for you

Comment: Yes because they contain useful metadata and gather several arrays that need to be used altogether

Comment: @Nihilum if you're getting errors using open_dataset or open_mfdataset feel free to post another question about it including the tracebacks :) but these are the methods I'd recommend for reading multiple netCDFs